Fullscreen a window without changing its aspect ratio or scaling level
I've been trying to find the Windows API to fullscreen a window without changing its aspect ratio or scaling level. I've gotten a window to fullscreen, but it leaves the sides transparent, and the UI is resized to fit this new window size. If possible, I just want to fullscreen the window without doing anything fancy, similar to how a game engine does it.
So far, I've tried fullscreening using this code:
style = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE)
style = style & ~(win32con.WS_CAPTION | win32con.WS_THICKFRAME)
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE, style)

